# How to save an image on the internet to local file in Python

Tags: python, image, save

I want to take direct image links from reddit and imgur, save them to file, and then upload them to twitter. There is no real reason I'm doing this, I just want the practice as I am new to programming. I am unsure on how to save an image link to file though. I came across a StackOverflow question that asked this same thing, and the answer that person was given was to use `urllib.retrieve`.

This is the code that I am using:

```
def post_to_twitter():
    if 'i.redd.it/' in submission.url or 'i.imgur.com/' in submission.url:
        print(submission.url)
        urllib.urlretrieve(str(submission.url),'<my directory>')
    elif 'i.redd.it/' not in submission.url or 'i.imgur.com/' not in submission.url:
        print('No direct imgur or reddit image link')
```

However, when I run this code, I get a unicode error that I have never come across before - `(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` and then IDLE highlights the comma that I used between the submission URL and my chosen directory.

Obviously this is the wrong code, I am sure that saving to file using an image link is not as easy as using a single line of code. What is it that I'm doing wrong, or is there just a better way to do this? If possible, could you please explain like I'm five. I'm new to programming and don't understand some words yet which get me confused.

---

**I found the solution**.

I actually managed to get this working with the original code I used, but slightly tweaked.

I used:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(submission.url, 'Reddit To Twitter Downloaded Images\\'+submission.id+'.jpeg')
```

`submission.url` returns the link to the image, so you can replace that with whatever you want, as long as it is equal to the direct image link as a string, such as `my_url = "http://i.imgur.com/qjMiF2A.gif"`

`'Reddit To Twitter Downloaded Images\\'+submission.id+'.jpeg'` is the name of the image you want to save. You can also specify the path in it. However, because I can't manually specify what I want the file to save as, I use the submission.id as the file name, so that way I can guarantee it will always be unique. I then just add `.jpeg` at the end of it to specify the file type.

Comment: Imgur won't work they are using react

Comment: Except that it does work. I edited my original question to include the solution, and posted an answer to this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to get this working with the original code I used, but slightly tweaked.

I used:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(submission.url, 'Reddit To Twitter Downloaded Images\\'+submission.id+'.jpeg')
```

`submission.url` returns the link to the image, so you can replace that with whatever you want, as long as it is equal to the direct image link as a string.

`'Reddit To Twitter Downloaded Images\\'+submission.id+'.jpeg'` is the name of the image you want to save. You can also specify the path in it. However, because I can't manually specify what I want the file to save as, I use the submission.id as the file name, so that way I can guarantee it will always be unique. I then just add `.jpeg` at the end of it to specify the file type.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
def saveImg(url,path,name):
    #url is imgurl 
    #path is your folder 
    #name is like tmp.png
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    try:
        response=urllib.request.urlopen(url);
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        return 0
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return 0
    code=response.read()
    filehandle=open(path+name,'wb');
    filehandle.write(code)
    filehandle.close()
    return 1
```

Comment: Nevermind, I actually managed to do it with that single line of code I had in my original post, but I change it up a bit to make it work. I posted the solution as an answer if you wanted to see how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pip `PIL` and `Requests` first
The cleanest way is

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
r=requests.get(name)
image=Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
image.save('{0}.jpg'.format("Image"))
```

Comment: When I try to `pip install PIL` I get this message - http://i.imgur.com/6LuFFlk.png

Comment: Nevermind, I actually managed to do it with that single line of code I had in my original post, but I change it up a bit to make it work. I posted the solution as an answer if you wanted to see how I did it.